# how to run external .exe application using groovy

Tags: groovy, exe

I am new to groovy. I need to run an external exe application using groovy. I have below code

```
def cmd = ['cmd', '/c', "c:\htmlimageconverter.exe"];
def sout = new StringBuilder();
def serr = new StringBuilder();
def proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process process = proc.start();
process.consumeProcessOutput( sout, serr );
process.waitForOrKill( 2000 );
```

It does not trigger that .exe file. If I change .exe to other .cmd script, the code is working.
Can someone let me know where i am wrong? Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this example:

```
String command = "wmic /user:userName /password:password /node:hostname cpu get loadpercentage"
def process = command.execute()
def outputStream = new StringBuffer()
process.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
String resultString = outputStream.toString()
```

If you just want to fire off something asynchronous, this will work in Groovy:

```
"taskkill /T /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe".execute().waitFor()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Below is my full code use your suggestion  

`def cmd = "taskkill /T /F /IM //172.21.175.59/Group/LinkDigiCom/EmailBounceReports/Email_Templates/htmlimageconverter/htmlimageconverter/bin/Debug/htmlimageconverter.exe"
def proc = cmd.execute().waitFor();`  
 
but still now working

Comment: No, no no. The taskkill /t /f /im is part of my command. Construct your command with parameters, make sure it works on the command line and then put it in quotes.

Comment: i only leave as `def cmd = "//172.21.175.59/Group/LinkDigiCom/EmailBounceReports/Email_Templates/htmlimageconverter/htmlimageconverter/bin/Debug/htmlimageconverter.exe"` still not working, if i just double click that exe applicaiton, it works, i just want to trigger the exe like double click, i don't have any parameters, really not sure where i am wrong.

Comment: Double clicking proves nothing. Go read up on running programs on shares from the command line. You *have* to get it working on the command line to see what the actual command is. I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for help. But i put below command line into Windows Command Prompt, it is working `//172.21.175.59/Group/LinkDigiCom/EmailBounceReports/Email_Templates/htmlimageconverter.exe`

Comment: @Nashearer I tried it now with an exe on a network host and it worked. Please just try one line: `"your command here".execute().waitFor()`

Comment: thanks again for your effort, i am just using below code `"//172.21.175.59/Group/LinkDigiCom/EmailBounceReports/Email_Templates/htmlimageconverter.exe".execute().waitFor()` still not trigger...